# easiest possible way to clear values of all controls in a div using jquery?

Tags: jquery, textbox

I have an add form inside a div which has 3-5 textboxes.. I submit the form via ajax and hide the div in the success function of it... Now i want to clear all the values of textboxes within the adddiv using jquery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If they're just text boxes (<input type="text"> fields), then $("form :input").val(""); would be the easiest way. If you have multiple types of inputs, though, you should check this out.

http://www.learningjquery.com/2007/08/clearing-form-data

It walks through how to create a plugin for clearing forms.

Answer (score 6):

```
$('#form input').attr('value','');
```

Resetting radio buttons and checkboxes:

```
$('#form input[type=radio]').attr('checked','');
```

Might be easier to combine that to:

```
$('#form input').attr('value','').attr('checked','');
```

But if it's for all the possible options, this should work too:

```
$('#form').each(function() {
  this.reset();
});
```

Comment: Became a long comment :) Edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input, select', $('#yourForm ')).val('');
```